# Android News App - do not download all json at once

Tags: android, json, listview, android-volley

I'm developing an android news app. Mobile client application gets the news from a web server through `HttpRequest` and 'HttpResponse`.

I used Volley to load images asynchronously with the help of [this article](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-volley/).

The question is if the news became too much during time, what would happen using the sample code in the article. As it has a loop on the response, it seems it download all `json`s at once.

```
 // Parsing json
                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                            try {

                                JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                Movie movie = new Movie();
                                movie.setTitle(obj.getString("title"));
                                movie.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("image"));
                                movie.setRating(((Number) obj.get("rating"))
                                        .doubleValue());
                                movie.setYear(obj.getInt("releaseYear"));

                                // Genre is json array
                                JSONArray genreArry = obj.getJSONArray("genre");
                                ArrayList<String> genre = new ArrayList<String>();
                                for (int j = 0; j < genreArry.length(); j++) {
                                    genre.add((String) genreArry.get(j));
                                }
                                movie.setGenre(genre);

                                // adding movie to movies array
                                movieList.add(movie);

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
```

What is the best approach in order not to download all jsons at once?

Comment: set a limit in the script that returns the JSON feed. take a look at this tutorial: http://www.androidhive.info/2015/05/android-swipe-down-to-refresh-listview-tutorial/ ,at the end of the page he adds the php code that can help you limit the data returned. all you need to do is arrange the data such that the relevant data is returned e.g. order by date descending

Comment: @Manny264 Would you please explain more as an answer,I'm newbie and I'll appreciate if you explain a bit more

Comment: check update @BzH the script is coming from a server that you mantain right?

Comment: Thanks @Manny264, your link was helpful

Comment: then a vote up would be nice :) @BzH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add pagination to the server. You definitely wouldn't want to download all the news articles from it. You need to limit the amount of data the server sends to the clients. Every time the client needs more data, you need to make an additional call to the server with the current offset.

Suppose that you hit an endpoint http://news.com/api which returns 25 articles. When the user consumes those 25 articles ( you probably want to do it before they consume all 25, so there's no lag), you make another call to the server telling it to send you 25 articles with an offset of 25: http://news.com/api?limit=25&offset=25

You cannot limit the server's response client side. This must be implemented on the server.